# Removing unwanted characters of a column in a Python DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

In a column A in Python DataFrame df, I have numbers column like `A= ['10', '20', '30', '14,200', '12,100', 50]`, I want to remove commas for all the rows of the column.

The result should be like `A= ['10', '20', '30', '14200', '12100', 50]`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
In [574]: df = pd.DataFrame(A, columns=['A'])                                                                                                                                                               

In [575]: df                                                                                                                                                                                                
Out[575]: 
        A
0      10
1      20
2      30
3  14,200
4  12,100
5      50

In [576]: df['A'] = df['A'].str.replace(',', '')                                                                                                                                                            

In [577]: df                                                                                                                                                                                                
Out[577]: 
       A
0     10
1     20
2     30
3  14200
4  12100
5     50
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the apply function in the DataFrame `df`

```
df['column_name'] = df['column_name'].apply(lambda x: str(x).replace(",",""))
```